# Shebang being mangled by rpmbuild

Tags: typescript, rpm, rpmbuild

When I build my rpm package the shebang in my script file is being changed. Here is a sample of the file contents with the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S npx ts-node -T

// Some Typescript code
let myArray:Array<number> = new Array<number>();
myArray.push(1);
myArray.push(2);
myArray.push(3);
console.log(myArray);
```

RPM Build Message

```
mangling shebang in /home/userx/bin/js/utils/test.ts from /usr/bin/env -S npx ts-node -T to 
#!/usr/bin/-S npx ts-node -T
```

Resulting file when installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/-S npx ts-node -T

// Some Typescript code
let myArray:Array<number> = new Array<number>();
myArray.push(1);
myArray.push(2);
myArray.push(3);
console.log(myArray);
```

The RPM build is done on the same machine as the install. /usr/bin/env exists. The script does run without errors in its original form. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a submitted issue #738 with the fedora-packaging group. Basically the issue was with old python scripts using shebangs. The request to mangle the

```
#!/usr/bin/env <anything>
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/<anything>
```

was accepted three years ago. My solution to adapt to the mangling by rpmbuild is to mangle the shebang that is going to be mangled as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env env -S npx ts-node -T
```

which results in my script containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S npx ts-node -T
```

Although this is very inconvenient to test locally before packaging for production it seems to be the best solution at the moment.

Another thought was to have a shebang as:

```
#!/usr/bin/envts -S npx ts-node -T
```

which would not be mangled by rpm build. I would then create a symbolic link

```
ln -s /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/envts
```

so that my Typescript script will run.